# Перенаправление для всех кроме одного ip-адреса

Tags: .htaccess

Мне нужно чтобы был Redirect с определённой страницы сайта на другую - для всех кроме указанных IP, им должна открываться правильная страница. Допустим есть кнопка, при переходе страница которая открывается только конкретным IP. Для других открывается другая страница, типа "Извините..."

Answer (score -1):

Сделай проще, в индексе напиши вроде такого:

```
<?php

$found = true;

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ) $page = 'landing';
else {
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $vardu = $page;
    if ( !preg_match('/^[A-z0-9\/-]{3,16}$/', $page) ) $found = false;
}

if ($found) {
    if ( file_exists('/'.$page.'.php') ) include '/'.$page.'.php';
    else $found = false;
}

if (!$found) {
    echo '404';
}

?>
```

Здесь обзерает урл, и перенаправляет на страницу /название страницы.php
Добавить правило вроде

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

и затем сравнить, если полученный айпи равен такому-то айпи, тогда только переход. Вроде такого:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' ) $page = 'landing';
else {
    $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
    $vardu = $page;
    if ( !preg_match('/^[A-z0-9\/-]{3,16}$/', $page) ) $found = false;
    if (твои айпи != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) $found = false;
}
```

Comment: Сайт на жуме )))